# how to end string in java when a double quote comes

Tags: java, web-services

I'm currently developing an online Multilingual Dictionary in JSP, for translation I'm using [microsoft-translator-java-api](https://github.com/boatmeme/microsoft-translator-java-api), and for finding meaning I'm using [services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService](http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx) dict service.

first I'm making request to [services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService](http://services.aonaware.com/DictService/DictService.asmx) dict service and I'm getting output after parsing

*WORD*

> know v 1: be cognizant or aware of a fact or a specific piece of information; possess knowledge or information about; "I know that the President lied to the people"; "I want to know who is winning the game!"; "I know it's time" ...

now I want to get

> be cognizant or aware of a fact or a specific piece of information; possess knowledge or information about

translated and I want

> "I know that the President lied to the people"

be the same so I want to split string when ever ""/ double quote comes any help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a String in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3481828/how-to-split-a-string-in-java)

Comment: So basically you want to split some string based on the position of a double-quote character. See the above link for a basic method ([`String.split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    String a = "a; \"b\". c";
    System.out.println("Original string:"+a);

    // split by "

    System.out.println("Split by \"");
    for (String string : a.split("\""))
    {
        System.out.println(string.replaceAll("[.;]", ""));
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but one thing what to do if I don't want to have `;` and `.` printed?

Comment: It is not duplicate. OP is not asking how to split, but how to split with a quote, which is not covered by the indicated answer.